# How does UISlider modify its appearance when disabled?

Tags: ios, uikit, uislider

I'm working on a custom slider UI element, and – at least in some respects – I'd like it to mimic `UISlider` as closely as possible. Right now I'm looking at the behavior of `UISlider` when its `enabled` property – inherited from `UIControl` – is set to false. Of `enabled`, [`UIControl`'s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) says:

> Specify YES to make the control enabled; otherwise, specify NO to make it disabled. The default value is YES. If the enabled state is NO, the control ignores touch events and subclasses may draw differently.

And, sure enough, `UISlider` draws itself differently when not enabled:

[image: UISlider enabled]
<sup>Enabled</sup>

[image: UISlider disabled]
<sup>Disabled</sup>

I'd like to know exactly what `UISlider` is doing to draw itself in this "faded out" way, so I can copy it.

My first instinct was that it was simply reducing its alpha, which would be very easy to imitate. However, upon closer inspection of the images, I realized that alpha can't account for the whole effect:

[image: UISlider enabled, zoomed]
<sup>Enabled, zoomed</sup>

[image: UISlider disabled, zoomed]
<sup>Disabled, zoomed</sup>

Looking at these two images, there appears to be some sort of blurring going on as well. It's especially noticeable on the blue minimum track image, which is a solid color in the zoomed, enabled image, but has an obvious vertical gradient in the zoomed, disabled image.

What's `UISlider` doing?

Comment: Never noticed that before. It does look to me as if a mild blur has been applied to the _entire_ slider.